# How can I submit a form with data and files by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Hello I'm trying to submit a form by ajax. It worked fine when I did not have files in the form. Now I have added files and I dont know how to add that information.
My code before adding the files was like this:

```
 var postData = form.serializeArray();
 $.ajax({
            url : 'my/url',
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                console.log('success');

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                console.log('Fail');
            }
        });
```

I've been looking at tutorials and they say to use the formData object to get the files. Something like this:

```
  if (files.length) {
         fileData = new FormData();
        $.each(files, function(key, value)
        {
            fileData.append(key, value);
        });
    }
```

so how can I append that to the `postData` variable and submit them together?

Edit:
I have tried to do this:

```
fileData = new FormData($('#form').serializeArray());
fileData = new FormData($('#form'));
```

I get the error:

```
illegal invocation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to pass the form into the constructor of the `FormData` than it is to iterate and add files to the data.

```
$( '#formId' )
  .submit( function( e ) {
    $.ajax( {
      url : 'my/url',
      type: 'POST',
      data: new FormData( this ),
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {
          console.log('success');

      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
      {
                console.log('Fail');
      }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```